# I'm in need of assistance with this if/else statement

Tags: php, html

I'm doing a contact page for my site, the text is in Portuguese because I'm Brazilian, but my problem is the following: when I send parameters with `?resp=true` it always enters in the first condition and I'm not able to figure out what is going wrong.

Why is the first condition met when the parameter is `?resp=true` ? , here is the code that I currently have problems on:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET["resp"]) && $_GET["resp"] == false) { ?>
    <div class="row row-centered" style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
            <strong style="text-align: center;">Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso.</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } elseif(isset($_GET["resp"]) && $_GET["resp"] == true) { ?>
    <div class="row row-centered" style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <div class='alert alert-danger'>
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
            <strong style="text-align: center;">Desculpe, parece que o servidor de email não esta respondendo. Por favor, tente novamente mais tarde!</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All values recieved via the POST or GET methods (ie. in the REQUEST) are automatically seen as strings. So trying to check:

```
<?php 
if($_GET['resp'] == true) {}
?>
```

will return false, and thus not enter the loop. What you want is to check the string value (instead of the boolean)

```
<?php 
if($_GET['resp'] == 'true') {)
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually trying to compare a string value to a boolean value. Since all that comes from form submit is in form of string only. So i have replaced boolean true and false with 'true' and 'false'

Try this code:

```
<?php if (isset($_GET["resp"]) && $_GET["resp"] == 'false') { ?>
    <div class="row row-centered" style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
            <strong style="text-align: center;">Sua mensagem foi enviada com sucesso.</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } elseif(isset($_GET["resp"]) && $_GET["resp"] == 'true') { ?>
    <div class="row row-centered" style="padding-top: 10px;">
        <div class='alert alert-danger'>
            <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
            <strong style="text-align: center;">Desculpe, parece que o servidor de email não esta respondendo. Por favor, tente novamente mais tarde!</strong>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Why should the OP "try this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Ok i will add explanation for the same.